# How to make SliverAppBar and SliverList height dynamic

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a screen which is composed of two parts, a calendar on top and a list on the bottom. When the list is scrolled (given it has several items), it should overlap on the calendar. Here is an example of how it should look like (and actually looks like with the code below, given the right circumstances) :

**Example of perfect layout**

[image: Example of perfect layout]

To achieve this layout, I've used a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar` and a `SliverList` :

```
CustomScrollView(
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  slivers: <Widget>[
    SliverAppBar(
      expandedHeight: _scaler.getHeight(65),
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        collapseMode: CollapseMode.none,
        background: Calendar(),
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
        <Widget>[
          Event(
            currentSelectedDay: _selectedDay!,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

The problem here is that when items in the SliverList are not enough to cover the remaining space, this is how it looks like in large screens :

**How the previous image looks in large screens**

[image: How the previous image looks in large screens]

As you can see, the `SliverList` takes a small space because it isn't big enough to fit the remaining space after the `SliverAppBar`. **Ideally, this is how it should look like**:

**How the previous image should actually look like**

[image: How the previous image should actually look like]

So any idea how can I actually make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in `_scaler.getHeight(65)`.

You can try `expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,`

---

Updated:
May be you can try to some invisible list items to `SliverChildBuilderDelegate` according to the screen height and item height as a temporary solution.

Comment: No, what I'd like to have is to get rid of expandedHeight altogether. Your solution would only change the appbar height and won't fix the list.

Comment: I see. May be you can try to some invisible list items to SliverChildBuilderDelegate according to the screen height and item height as a temporary solution.